# Deleting an item from my shopping cart. Code deletes wrong item when deleting 2nd item

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to create button to a delete specific items out of my shopping cart, and so far it somewhat works. The problem is that it's not consistent. When I try to delete the 2nd item, it deletes the 3rd item, and when there are two items in the cart and I delete the second one, it doesn't do anything when the button is clicked. I must have missed something.

I have data being pulled out from my database, and I am starting `i` at 1.

```
$i=1;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
```

This is what I have tried. My form looks like this..

```
    <form action='cart.php' method='post'>
<input name='deleteBtn" . $item_id . "'type='submit' value='Remove This Item' />
<input name='index_to_remove' type='hidden' value='" . $i . "' /></form>

 i++;
```

And to remove the item, I have:

```
if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "") {
    // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
    $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
    if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
        //In case I want it to sort - sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
}
```

Can you help?

Comment: Remember that arrays in PHP are 0-based (unless you manually specified them)

Comment: I am. I have specified my multidim array to start at 1.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted never increments `$i`, so `$_POST['index_to_remove']` is always `1`. This is going to delete `$_SESSION["cart_array"]["1"]` every time.

It's impossible to tell from this code which item has index `"1"` in `$_SESSION["cart_array"]`, but the key point is that you are using the same value for `$_POST['index_to_remove']` for every item.

Comment: @user3150191 Then you need to post that code; we can't help you find the problem if you don't post all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the index (keys) of the array. Arrays are lists of key=>value pairs:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $key => $each_item) {
  ...
}
```

Now use that key in your form:

```
<input name='index_to_remove' type='hidden' value='" . $key . "' />
```

And finaly unset the array_key (if it exists):

```
...
$key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];

if(array_key_exists($key_to_remove, $_SESSION["cart_array"])){
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"][$key_to_remove]);
}
....
```

**Suggestion:** Since you have a (unique) item_id to start with, why not use that item_id as key (identifier) in your array to start with? Instead of having it in your values.

So this:

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"][0] = array(
      'item_id' => 'IdOfYourItem',
      'item_name' => 'nameOfYourItem',
      'quantity' => 1,
      'other_key' => 'otherValue'
      );
```

could be this:

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"]['IdOfYourItem'] = array(
      'item_name' => 'nameOfYourItem',
      'quantity' => 1,
      'other_key' => 'otherValue'
      );
```

Comment: What I think is happening is that when $i is deleted, the items change, so $i = 3, becomes $i = 2 after the first $i = 2 was deleted. If I try to delete $i=2 again, it doesn't let me. Is there a way to update the code so it refreshes somehow? Other than that, it's working the way I had it.